Action of a polynomial matrix on a vector of vectors
I am currently taking a first graduate course in Linear Algebra. Recently we defined the action of $\mathbb{F}[x]$ on vector space $V$ via a linear function $f:V\to V$ in the following way:

For any $h(x)\in\mathbb{F}[x]$ and any $v\in V$, define $$h(x) \cdot v = h(f)(v)$$

We then went on to show that

Lemma: For any $h_1(x), h_2(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ and $ v \in V$, $$h_1(x)\cdot (h_2(x) \cdot v)=(h_1(x) h_2(x))\cdot v$$

This all made sense to me, although I am a bit unsure of the exact meaning of notation $h(x)$ (does this mean $h$ evaluated at argument $x$, like usual?).
The instructor then went on to write

For any matrix $H\in \mathbb{F}[x]^{m\times n}$ and any $v=(v_1, \dotsc , v_n) \in V^n$, where $v_i \in V,$ we have $H\cdot v\in V^m$. Now from the previous Lemma, for any $v\in V^n$, $H\in \mathbb{F}[x]^{m\times n}$, $G\in \mathbb{F}[x]^{t \times m}$, we have $$G\cdot (H\cdot v) = (GH)\cdot v$$

I understand how this would follow from the Lemma if $\mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$, for example, were a field, but this is obviously not the case (in general).
How does this follow from the Lemma? Also, does $H\cdot v$ involve the same "dot" binary operator as before?
Note: I don't have a strong background in Abstract Algebra. Also, please edit this question or its title if you find any terminology to be nonstandard.

The multiplication of a matrix in $\mathbb{F}(x)$ by a vector in $V$ follows the same notation as usual matrix multiplication. Explicitly:
$$(H\cdot v)_i=\sum_{j=1}^n H_{i, j}(x) \cdot v_j, \quad H\in \mathbb{F}(x)^{m\times n}, \ v\in V,$$
where, as you can see, I explicitly wrote $H_{i, j}(x)$ to indicate that each element of the matrix $H$ belongs to $\mathbb{F}(x)$.
Using this fact and analyzing both $G\cdot (H\cdot v)$ and $(GH)\cdot v$ by components, it is not difficult to conclude that the lemma proves the equality $G\cdot (H\cdot v) = (GH)\cdot v.$
